# Data Validation referring to a column in a table less few cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list in Column D of a Table: D2: None, D3: Custom, D4: Ceaserstone, D5: Silestone, where D1: StoneBenchtop is the heading.

The table is named DataValid.

I created a Named Range called StoneBenchtop which refers to DataValid[StoneBenchtop].

In cell E3, if I create a data validation referring to StoneBenchtop, I get this list: None, Custom, Ceaserstone, Silestone. I do not want "None & Custom" to come up in the list this time, but I want to keep the list Dynamic. Also, I don't want to delete "None & Custom" from the named range as another cell is referring to StoneBenchtop and this cell needs the whole list.

Please help.

Comment: The answers under [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/exclude-item-in-list-from-data-validation/967990a9-976a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) question propose a few different ways to do this, they might help someone find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by name manager. It doesn't refer on table but on dynamic range. It is not clean, but I think, it solve your problem.

1. Create "New Name" in name manager

[image]

2. Refers to: =$D$4:INDEX($D$4:$D$2000;MATCH("Ω";$D$4:$D$2000))
3. Name: RangeStoneBenchtop
4. Now "Data Validation Source" will be =RangeStoneBenchtop